# How do you show output of assert in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, assert

```
console.log 'before'
assert 1 is 2
console.log 'after'
```

When I run `meteor`, all that is printed is 'before', and nothing about an assertion failing. The assert package has been added with `meteor add assert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (looks like you're using coffeescript):

```coffeescript
console.log 'before'

try
  assert 1 is 2
catch error
  console.log error.message

console.log 'after'
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know of a way to get Meteor to log all thrown exceptions? Or in particular those thrown on the server side of a method.

Comment: Do you want them to be logged to the Node.js console, the browser console, a log file, a log collection, etc? However you are logging exceptions, you could always wrap the inner code of your methods in a try/catch block. It wouldn't be hard to abstract this into a more reusable wrapper function that does your error logging. Just basic first-class functions.

Comment: Would be awesome if all exceptions thrown were logged to the console, at least in development mode... :-)